# Datastore Batch Query Size

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-api-java-client

I'm trying to understand the behavior of the [Google Cloud Java Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-java) to make batch queries against Datastore (datastore on the old backend, not Firestore in 'Datastore Mode').  It seems I'm unable to configure the total number of results that are returned from 'runBatchQuery', I'm looking for confirmation that this Github answer is the definitive answer for the how batch queries work in Datastore:

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/issues/1319

Basically, does the end user have no control of the batch size using the Datastore Java library to run queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As documented in the [reference](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/datastore/StructuredQuery.html) and the [getting started](https://cloud.google.com/java/getting-started/using-cloud-datastore) guide, you can use setLimit to limit the batch size for your queries.  What are you looking to do with a different batch size?

Comment: My question boils down to what determines the amount of records returned if a limit is not set.  Is the total number of records pulled down when running a query based on a limit of the max amount of data that can be returned in a single Datastore API call?

Comment: There are few things that go into max batch size, including the number of entities, and the response size.